# one .h and .m file for multiple xib ios

Tags: ios, iphone, class, xib

I want to create one `.h` and `.m` class for multiple `.xib` like template.
is it possible ? an if yes then how to use one `.h` an `.m` file for multiple `xib` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure can! :D you'll just have to load the xib file with `-initWithNibFile:bundle:`. And in each of the xib's make sure the **File's Owner** class is set to the view controller of the .h .m

I hope this is what you're looking for :)